# Ошибка flutter_local_notifications Targeting S+ (version 31 and above)

Tags: android-sdk, flutter, mobile-development

Есть код для мобильного приложения на flutter для получения уведомлений

```
Future _showNotificationRequest() async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
        playSound: true,
        importance: Importance.Max,
        priority: Priority.High,
        ticker: 'ticker');
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        new IOSNotificationDetails(presentSound: false);
    var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      'Новые заявки',
      'Обновите список заявок',
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'No_Sound',
    );
  }
```

После изменения версии SDK на 31, так как Google Play не дает сейчас ставить ниже

```
compileSdkVersion 31
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "kz.vashdomofon.ksu"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Появилась ошибка выполнения этого метода

```
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(29530): Compat change id reported: 160794467; UID 10146; state: ENABLED
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: kz.vashdomofon.ksu: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530): Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:458)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:444)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:408)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.createNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:134)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:688)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:827)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:750)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:84)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:865)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:161)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: kz.vashdomofon.ksu: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530): Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:458)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:444)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:408)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.createNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:134)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:688)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:827)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:750)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:84)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:865)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:161)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(29530):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
E/flutter (29530): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, kz.vashdomofon.ksu: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
E/flutter (29530): Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles., null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: kz.vashdomofon.ksu: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
E/flutter (29530): Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
E/flutter (29530):  at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
E/flutter (29530):  at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:458)
E/flutter (29530):  at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:444)
E/flutter (29530):  at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:408)
E/flutter (29530):  at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.createNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:134)
E/flutter (29530):  at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:688)
E/flutter (29530):  at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:827)
E/flutter (29530):  at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:750)
E/flutter (29530):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/flutter (29530):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:84)
E/flutter (29530):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:865)
E/flutter (29530):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (29530):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/flutter (29530):  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:161)
E/flutter (29530):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/flutter (29530):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
E/flutter (29530):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (29530):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/flutter (29530):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
E/flutter (29530): )
E/flutter (29530): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
E/flutter (29530): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
E/flutter (29530): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29530): #2      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show
E/flutter (29530): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29530): #3      _KSU._showNotificationRequest
E/flutter (29530): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29530):
E/flutter (29530): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, kz.vashdomofon.ksu: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
E/flutter (29530): Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles., null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: kz.vashdomofon.ksu: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
E/flutter (29530): Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
E/flutter (29530):  at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
E/flutter (29530):  at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:458)
E/flutter (29530):  at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:444)
E/flutter (29530):  at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:408)
E/flutter (29530):  at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.createNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:134)
E/flutter (29530):  at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:688)
E/flutter (29530):  at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:827)
E/flutter (29530):  at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:750)
E/flutter (29530):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/flutter (29530):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:84)
E/flutter (29530):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:865)
E/flutter (29530):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (29530):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/flutter (29530):  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:161)
E/flutter (29530):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/flutter (29530):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
E/flutter (29530):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (29530):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/flutter (29530):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
E/flutter (29530): )
E/flutter (29530): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
E/flutter (29530): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
E/flutter (29530): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29530): #2      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show
E/flutter (29530): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29530): #3      _KSU._showNotificationPPR
E/flutter (29530): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Каким образом исправить эту ошибку так и не нашел, или решения не подходили именно для моего случая. Может кто покажет в какую сторону хотя бы копать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решилось обновлением пакетов и обновлением gradle